# Using *args and keywords in function definition causes error

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a function definition as follows:

```
def test(self, *args, wires=None, do_queue=True):
    pass
```

In Python3, this runs normally, but in Python2 it crashes with a SyntaxError. How can I modify it to work in Python2?

Comment: Put `*args` as the last argument.

Comment: @JohnGordon: That's going to be a major behavioral change, though.

Comment: @JohnGordon: Specifically, with your change, `instance.test(obj)` will use `obj` as the value of `wires` instead of as the first element of `args`. In most conceivable use cases, this is a complete functionality break.

Comment: @user2357112: Beyond that, you can't pass the defaulted arguments by keyword at all without breaking your ability to pass the positional arguments in `*args`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to make this work in Python 2 is to accept your keyword-only arguments as `**kwargs` and extract them manually. Python 2 has no ability to do keyword-only arguments in any other manner; it was [a new feature of Python 3 to allow this at all](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).

The closest Python 2 equivalent would be:

```
def test(self, *args, **kwargs):
    wires = kwargs.pop('wires', None)
    do_queue = kwargs.pop('do_queue', True)
    if kwargs:
        raise TypeError("test got unexpected keyword arguments: {}".format(kwargs.keys()))
```